# Use Oracle Analytic functions to speed up a COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have to get a query to perform better:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.ID)
  FROM MY_TABLE T
 WHERE T.DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/12/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), -6) AND
       LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/12/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

this query outputs the number of distinct occurrences of that flag over the period of 6 months prior the reference date.

I tried using Oracle Analytic functions but none of the examples found online work and neither what I came out with:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.ID) OVER(RANGE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/12/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), -6) AND LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/12/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')))
  FROM MY_TABLE T;
```

Am i missing something or what I'm trying to accomplish simply isn't worth Analytic functions or is just wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Analytic functions are not for performance. You should probably try to add index for date,id

Comment: I do have an Id for the date but the extraction is still taking a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try use GROUP BY. Sometimes, is fastest. If you have not an index on DATE field, you can perform a full table scan with parallel option.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM
(SELECT /*+ FULL(T) PARALLEL(T)*/ T.ID
FROM MY_TABLE T
WHERE T.DATE BETWEEN 
ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/12/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), -6) 
AND
LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/12/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
GROUP BY T.ID);
```